# EOL while scanning string literal when trying to print a \ in python

Tags: python, printing, eol

I'm trying to print just a `\` using python and it seems like `\` is some kind of reserved character or something. The code `print "\"` returns `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash is used in Python for [escape sequences](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). The proper way to do what you want is:

```
print "\\" # You need to escape the \ character
```

Comment: @user2117821 No problem. BTW, I added code formatting to your question... if you're new to StackOverflow code formatting you might want to take a look at the edit for future reference. Additionally it's good practice to copy and paste in the actual error... both for people searching the question to find the answer more easily and for the people trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't end a string with a `\` character since you could be asking it to escape the `"` character.  You need to use `"\\"`